# Is it possible to load up the native camera via Air native extensions?

Tags: android, flash, android-camera, android-activity, air-native-extension

As per the title really...

Is it possible to load up the native camera via Air native extensions?

We've created a native extension (iOS & Android) and the iOS portion works fine (loading up the native camera control) but when implementing the same on Android we can't get the camera to appear on the stage, no errors, just nothing! So this got me wondering is it actually possible?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve that the Camera class doesn't already give you?
The "native" Camera can be attached to the stage as so:

```
var camera:Camera;
var display:Video;

camera = Camera.getCamera("0");
display = new Vide(stage.fullScreenWidth, stage.fullScreenHeight);
display.attachCamera(camera);
addChild(display);
```

You can set the quality / mode / etc. on the camera object as required. If you want to access the camera app on the device you need to use CameraUI instead, which gives you more end user control but restricts what you can do with the captured data.